# Page Not Found, When i am opening new Page(GET)

Tags: python, django

I created a new account and when I try to open new form, it says, `Page Not found`

view.py

```
def Hfapplication(request):
    user = request.GET.get("user_id", request.user.id)
    print(user) 
    host_family = get_object_or_404(hfmodel, pk=user)
    context = {'exists': True, 'existing_hfmodel': host_family}
    if request.method=='GET':

       form =Forms.HFForm(instance=host_family)
       context['form']=form
       return render(request, 'hfapplication.html', context)
       print("hii")
    elif request.method =='POST':
       form = Forms.HFForm(data=request.POST, instance=host_family, files=request.FILES)
       context['form']=form
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          submit = form.cleaned_data['submitted']
          if submit:

               context['msg]']= "submitted"
               return render(request,"submittedApp.html", context)


          context['msg]']= "saved"
          return render(request, "submittedApp.html", context)
```

this is my view where i am getting error

This is my model, i am not sure why i am problem. I also checked by removing Primary key but still having same problem

```
class hfmodel(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, db_column='user', related_name="host_family", on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
drop_down1 = models.CharField(max_length=300, choices=USER_DORPDOWN1, null=True, blank=True)
drop_down3 = models.CharField(max_length=300, choices=USER_DORPDOWN3, null=True, blank=True)
schoollist = models.CharField(max_length=300, choices=HF_School, null=True, blank=True)
namelocal =  models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
hfschool = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)

#Host Father Informatin
hffn = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
hfln = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
birth_date1 = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
hfoccupation = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
hfemp = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
hfwph = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
hfcph = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
hfedu = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
hfemail = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
hfcrim = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
ethnicbckf = models.CharField(max_length=300, choices=USER_DORPDOWN5, null=True, blank=True)
ethnicbckf_other = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, default="", blank=True)
```

enter code here'

Comment: what's `hfmodel`? why are you getting it with `pk=user`? Are you sure the primary key of `hfmodel` is the same as the user's id?

Comment: Share your `urls.py` file, the mistake should be inside.

Comment: no, it's not urls.py that gives the problem, it's your model, show us `hfmodel`.

Comment: this is my model.